# How can I decorate a HttpServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, delegates, decorator, servlet-3.0

I need to make a wrapper class for HttpServlet. The problem is that the `doX` methods are protected and for this reason i can't apply any delegator unless i create some kind of `HttpServletWithPublicMethods extends HttpServlet` subclass (Which i don't want to).

The intended usage is the following:

`servletContext.addServlet("myServletName", new HttpServletWrapper(myServlet))`

Is there any way to circumvent this? I guess calling `Method#invoke` would be costly in this case.

Comment: You may want to do it with a servlet filter. Depending on the exact use case, servlet filters can be considered a decorator for HTTP requests, just as your `HttpServletWrapper` would be a decorator for Java method calls.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos my intent was to extend the "doX" methods directly, so i didn't want the filters to be involved. Anyway, the only public method is the "service()" method (which makes sense since HttpServlet implements the Servlet interface)  so i guess the best choice would be to decorate the "service()" method instead of the "doX" methods. In the end i came up with inheritance with this solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272887/interceptor-mechanism-for-httpservlets